# Subscript out of range in qbasic loop of fibonacci series

Tags: qbasic

```
declare function fibo()
CALL fibo
END
SUB fibo ()
    n(1) = 1
    n(2) = 1
    PRINT n(1); n(2)
    FOR i = 3 TO 10
        s(i) = n(i - 1) + n(i - 2)
        PRINT s(i)
    NEXT
END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
declare function fibo()
PRINT "fibonacci series"
CALL fibo
END

SUB fibo ()
    DIM n(10) AS INTEGER
    FOR i = 3 TO 10
        n(1) = 1
        n(2) = 1
        n(i) = n(i - 1) + n(i - 2)
        PRINT n(i)
    NEXT
END FUNCTION
```